# Can't use RSpec's controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I got following error when I run `spec/controllers/companies_controller_spec.rb`.

```
undefined method `get' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::CompaniesController::Nested_2:Class (NoMethodError)
```

To enable `get` method, I added a line in `spec/rails_helper.rb`.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Unfortunately there was no effect, therefore I added `type: :controller` like this:

```
describe CompaniesController, type: :controller do
  #...
end
```

But still I get same `` undefined method `get' `` error.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post more code from `spec/controllers/companies_controller_spec.rb`? Without this it's hard to tell.. Maybe you forgot to put `get` inside `it` block? Or forgot `require 'rails_helper'` in this file?

Comment: Exactly as you speculated, I was not put it inside `it` block. Thanks!